# QSqlError("", "Parameter count mismatch", "") On qt

Tags: c++, sql, qt

i'm tryng to add something on datebase, but it give me this error (QSqlError("", "Parameter count mismatch", "")...

```
int GereVendas::addVenda(int idFuncionario, int idCliente) {

DB *db = new DB();
if(!db->checkDbOpen()){
    db->openDB();
    qDebug() << "a abrir base de dados";
}

if(db->checkDbOpen()){
    QSqlQuery query;
    QDateTime dateTime = dateTime.currentDateTime();

    query.prepare("INSERT INTO VENDA (P_ID_PESSOA, CLI_P_ID_PESSOA, V_Nome, V_MetodoPagamento, V_ValorTotal, V_Data, V_Estado) "
                  "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    query.addBindValue(idFuncionario);
    query.addBindValue(idCliente);
    query.addBindValue("test");
    query.addBindValue("test");
    query.addBindValue(12);
    query.addBindValue(dateTime);
    query.addBindValue(1);

    if(query.exec()) {
        QSqlDatabase::database().commit();
        db->closeDB();
        return 1;
    }

    qDebug() << query.lastQuery(); //show this: ""
    qDebug() << query.lastError(); //show this: QSqlError("", "Parameter count mismatch", "")

} else {
    qDebug() << "Error!DB not open!";
}
db->closeDB();
qDebug() << "Error";
return -1;
}
```

My table of db is this: (V_ID is auto_increment)

[image]

Comment: Does `query.boundValues().values().size()` return 7 as expected?

Comment: Yes, returns 7!...

Comment: I have found many problems are easier to debug if I print out the values being passed and the query and then manually execute the query through the databases SQL interface directly. (e.g. run mysql, then type the query into the mysql prompt)

Comment: +1 to running the query directly, but a few other ideas:  Does `query.prepare(...)` return true?  What SQL driver are you using?  Just as a sanity check, I might also verify that `query.driver()->hasFeature(QSqlDriver::PreparedQueries)` returns `true` as well as the same for `QSqlDriver::PositionalPlaceholders`.